# How to check if day is passed?

Tags: php, imap

I am working on my PHP to fetch the date from the emails. I want to set up the date to 30 days using the date from the emails so I could compare with my current date that if the day have passed or not.

Here is the output for the date:

```
Fri, 13 Sep 2019 20:27:47 +0200
Sun, 8 Sep 2019 21:10:55 +0100
Sun, 8 Sep 2019 21:09:24 +0100
Sun, 8 Sep 2019 21:05:56 +0100
```

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php

require_once "Mail.php";
require_once('Mail/IMAPv2.php');

// Connect to the server:
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$email_number = '';

$spam = '{imap.example.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX.spam';
$spam = imap_open($spam, $username, $password) or die("Can't connect: " . imap_last_error());

if (PEAR::isError($spam)) {
    echo "<span style='font-weight: bold;'>Error:</span> Unable to build a connection.";
}
else
{
    //$spam_emails = imap_search($spam, 'ALL');
    $spam_emails = imap_sort($spam, SORTARRIVAL, 1, SE_UID);

    if($spam_emails !== false) {
        //rsort($spam_emails);
        $res_spam_emails = NavForList($spam_emails, $start_ind);
        $temp_spam_emails = $res_spam_emails['result'];
        $start_idx = $res_spam_emails['start_idx'];
        $limit_idx = $res_spam_emails['limit_idx'];
        $total = $res_spam_emails['total'];
        $total_inbox_unread = count(imap_search($inbox, 'UNSEEN'));
        $total_draft_unread = count(imap_search($draft, 'UNSEEN'));
        $total_spam_unread = count(imap_search($spam, 'UNSEEN'));
        $html = "";

        foreach($temp_spam_emails as $email_number) {
            $overview = imap_fetch_overview($spam, $email_number, FT_UID);
            $spam_from = $overview[0]->from;
            //$spam_subject = utf8_decode(imap_utf8($overview[0]->subject));
            $spam_subject = quoted_printable_decode($overview[0]->subject);
            $spam_date = $overview[0]->date;

            $expiry_date = date($spam_date, strtotime('+30 days'));
            echo $expiry_date;
        }
    }
    imap_close($spam);
}
?>
```

I have tried this:

```
$expiry_date = date($spam_date, strtotime('+30 days'));
echo $expiry_date;
```

It give me the output like this:

```
OctoberMon, 14 Oct 2019 22:39:12 +000039, 13 thUTCp 2019 20:27:47 +0200
th00000010, 8 thUTCp 2019 21:10:55 +0100
th00000010, 8 thUTCp 2019 21:09:24 +0100
th00000010, 8 thUTCp 2019 21:05:56 +0100
```

Here is what I want to achieve:

```
Sun, 13 Oct 2019 20:27:47 +0200
Tues, 8 Oct 2019 21:10:55 +0100
Tues, 8 Oct 2019 21:09:24 +0100
Tues, 8 Oct 2019 21:05:56 +0100
```

Can you please show me an example how I could set up the date to 30 days using the variable `$spam_date` and how I could also check if the day have passed or not?

Thank you.

Comment: What is in `$spam_date` ? you can use DateTime and `->add(new DateInterval("P30D"));`

Comment: Accountant The `$spam_date` is the date that I have already output, example: `Fri, 13 Sep 2019 20:27:47 +0200`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$spam_date = "Fri, 13 Sep 2019 20:27:47 +0200";
$expiryDate = new \DateTime($spam_date);
$expiryDate->add(new \DateInterval("P30D"));
echo $expiryDate->format("c") . "\n";// ISO 8601 format
//2019-10-13T20:27:47+02:00
echo $expiryDate->format("r") . "\n";//RFC 2822 format
//Sun, 13 Oct 2019 20:27:47 +0200
$now = new \DateTime("now");
if ($expiryDate < $now){
    echo "expiry time is passed";
} else {
    echo "expiry time is not passed";
}

exit;
//outputs
//2019-10-13T20:27:47+02:00 
//Sun, 13 Oct 2019 20:27:47 +0200 
//time is not passed
```

Live Demo https://3v4l.org/OeGRX

Comment: Thank you for this, but you have got it wrong. On the code you wrote, the current day did not passed on 30 days as it is not Oct 13 yet. Please fix your code.

Comment: @chrisoojer Do mean you want to compare `now+30 days` against the `spam_date` ?

Comment: Yes I want to compare 30 days against the `spam_date` whether if the day have been passed or not.